# Google sheet : How to add link to jump to specific cell of other sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

While working on my spreadsheet, I want a 'button' to link or jump to specific cell of other sheet in the same spreadsheet.

If I add image over cell then I can assign a script function and it works fine. But I want the image to be inside a cell not over the cells. The problem is if I put the image inside the cell, I no longer can click it (or can't assign script).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For linking to a cell, use `=HYPERLINK()` formula:

```
=HYPERLINK("#gid=[SHEET_ID]&range=[A1_NOTATION]")
```

where,

- `[SHEET_ID]` is the id of a sheet usually shown in the url hash(eg:1134456 in `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/[SPREADSHEET_ID]/edit#gid=1134456`)
- `[A1_NOTATION]` is range's A1 notation. eg: A1

Answer (score 2):

I believe your goal as follows.

- For Google Spreadsheet, you want to put an image button into a cell, and want to jump to other cell on other sheet in the same Spreadsheet when the button is clicked.

### Issue and workaround:

In the current stage, unfortunately, the image put in a cell cannot be assigned by a function. So in this case, as a workaround, I would like to propose to use the OnSelectionChange trigger of the simple trigger.

### Usage:

In order to use this workaround, please do the following flow.

#### 1. Put image to a cell.

Please put an image to a cell. In this case, as a sample, please put an image into a cell "A1" of "Sheet1".

#### 2. Sample script.

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Spreadsheet.

```
function onSelectionChange(e) {
  const range = e.range;
  if (range.getSheet().getSheetName() != "Sheet1" || range.getA1Notation() != "A1") return;
  const jumpTo = "Sheet2!A1";
  e.source.getRange(jumpTo).activate();
}
```

#### 3. Testing.

In this sample script, when the cell "A1" of "Sheet1" is clicked, the function of `onSelectionChange` is automatically run by firing the trigger, and the cell of "A1" in "Sheet2" is activated.

### Note:

- This is a simple sample script for testing this workaround. So please modify this for your actual situation.

### Reference:

- [onSelectionChange(e)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onselectionchangee)

Answer (score 0):

to jump one sheet to another sheet through script try these lines on specific cell click event

```
//get active sheet
var currentSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
currentSheet.setActiveSheet("Sheet2"); // Sheet2 is name of next sheet
```